# query table as json result for ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax

I have created a button, to popup a model page with a table from database. I have created a model page in the view and I have a method in controller to query the data from three tables as a new table to display in the model

```
public ActionResult GetRate()
{
MTUNOW=new MTUNOW;
var day=new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year(), DateTime.Now.Month(), DateTime.Now.Date()); 
var RateList=(from r in dbAccess.Rates.GetAll() where c.Date==day join from c in dbAccess.Cities.GetAll() on r.CID Equals c.CID join from co in dbAccess.Countries.GetAll() on c.ID Equals co.ID select new{country=co.name, city=c.name, rate=r.rate}.ToList();        
return json(RateList);
}
```

as this is the method i wrote to create a table but it throws a null reference and how can i get this table to the model using ajax please help me to make this work thanks in advance

Comment: sorry it my mistake its the List

Comment: in which line you are getting exception?and what it says..show us details

Comment: There isn't enough information here to determine what you actual issue is but seeing as though there are no parameters being posted to GetRate() then I'm assuming you're calling GetRate() with a get request. Try adding return Json(RateList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)